# For iis-express on terminal services, can I limit connections to just the current user/session

Tags: terminal-server, iis-express

I'd like to run iis-express within a user session on a windows terminal services server.

However, I'd like only my current user to have access to the iis-express hosted site. Is there a way of achieving this, or does localhost have to be available to all users on that server?

Answer (score 0):

Is it for a specific user, or just the *current* user? If a specific user, you can set the site to use Windows Authentication and only give rights to the site to that user.

Comment: Ideally it's the current user - I'd like it to be possible to run different IIS express instances (on different ports) in each user session.